# H2 Database - "Unknown data type" with empty data type

Tags: java, sql, h2

I'm getting a very weird error from H2 where it tells me that it doesn't know a data type but doesn't tell me which one it is.

That's the error message:

```
Unknown data type: ; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE bans (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, player_id INT NOT NULL, operator_id INT NOT NULL, end DATETIME NULL, reason VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), INDEX (player_id), INDEX (end), FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES players(id), FOREIGN KEY (operator_id) REFERENCES players(id)) [50004-200]
```

and this is the SQL query in plain:

```sql
CREATE TABLE bans (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, player_id INT NOT NULL, operator_id INT NOT NULL, end DATETIME NULL, reason VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), INDEX (player_id), INDEX (end), FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES players(id), FOREIGN KEY (operator_id) REFERENCES players(id))
```

I neither understand what H2 is trying to tell me, nor do I see what's wrong with that query. I tried playing around with the spacing but to no avail.

**Edit 1:**

I'm opening the database connection with this JDBC string:

```
jdbc:h2:%s;AUTO_SERVER=%s;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE
```

(And using `String.format` to set the two appropriate values. First one naturally being the base file name and the second either `TRUE` or `FALSE` (either work).)

I am not changing any other settings or enabling any other modes. The only thing I do is create 2 tables before and inserting a bit of data into them.

Comment: H2 1.4.200 accepts `SET MODE MySQL;
CREATE TABLE PLAYERS(ID INT);
CREATE TABLE bans (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, player_id INT NOT NULL, operator_id INT NOT NULL, end DATETIME NULL, reason VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), INDEX (player_id), INDEX (end), FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES players(id), FOREIGN KEY (operator_id) REFERENCES players(id));` without any exceptions. You need to provide a complete test case that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't set a compatibility mode for non-standard definition of an index.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov I'm not using MySQL mode though. Just `DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use non-standard `INDEX(player_id)` and `INDEX(end)` in H2 without a MySQL compatibility mode. (Actually database indexes aren't covered by the Standard.)

Either use a MySQL compatibility mode, or use a separate `CREATE INDEX` command such as

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON bans(end);
```

Index on `player_id` column is not needed, because non-unique index will be created automatically by H2 for constraint `FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES players(id)`.

Please also note that behavior of `DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE` was changed since 1.4.198. With this setting all column names are case-sensitive. You may want to use `DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE` instead.

Comment: It’s the small things sometimes... Though what weird error message nonetheless. And thank you for the tip with the alternative flag. I used it originally to have the same capitalizations as the other database I use in the that software. Good to know I can force them to be lowercase.

Comment: Current H2 throws `Syntax error in SQL statement "… PRIMARY KEY (ID), INDEX ([*]PLAYER_ID), INDEX (END), …"; expected "IDENTITY, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL, data type"`, such message is more or less reasonable, a data type of the `INDEX` column is expected instead of `(`.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to watch out for are **forbidden characters in column names**.
e.g. if you use a column name such as `@Column(name="my-column")` then you'll actually see the exact same error message.

```
Unknown data type: ; SQL statement:
```

When you're really stuck, connect to the console webpage of the database, and try to execute the query there. (There's usually a query in the exception message).

If you run an embedded H2 database, then you can enable the console webpage by setting the following properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

# view database on http://localhost:8080/h2-console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you get this exception when you have the same function in H2 and in your dev DB, but the functionality is not the same:

For example CONVERT function in H2 and Orcacle.

In this case you can override the H2 function when you put this in your H2 URL: BUILTIN_ALIAS_OVERRIDE=1;

Then you have to create an alias in your test resources sql:

CREATE
ALIAS CONVERT FOR "com.example.config.H2Functions.convert";

Then create this class with the emethod in java:

```
public class H2Functions {

public static String convert(String param1, String param2) {
    return StringUtils.stripAccents(param1);
}}
```

If you are using Junit5 you have to implement org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeEachCallback;

```
    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
         DataSource dataSource = getDataSource(context);
         backupDatabase(dataSource);
    }

    private void backupDatabase(DataSource dataSource) {
        try {
            Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            RunScript.execute(connection, IOUtils.getReader(H2Extension.class.getResourceAsStream("/h2_functions.sql")));
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

And put these annotations on your test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, H2Extension.class})
```